# C# - Drawing a Rounded Rectangle on a panel

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to draw a gradient filled rounded rectangle onto a panel `bar` in a form.

From some research I found some code that allowed me to create a custom rectangle :

```
static class CustomRectangle 
{
    public static GraphicsPath RoundedRect(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Size size = new Size(diameter, diameter);
        Rectangle arc = new Rectangle(bounds.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        if (radius == 0)
        {
            path.AddRectangle(bounds);
            return path;
        }

        // top left arc  
        path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);

        // top right arc  
        arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);

        // bottom right arc  
        arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);

        // bottom left arc 
        arc.X = bounds.Left;
        path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);

        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }

    public static void FillRoundedRectangle(this Graphics graphics, Brush brush, Rectangle bounds, int cornerRadius)
    {
        if (graphics == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("graphics");
        if (brush == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("brush");

        using (GraphicsPath path = RoundedRect(bounds, cornerRadius))
        {
            graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
        }
    }
```

Credit to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853434/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-in-c-sharp)

Next using this custom rectangle, I have tried using the `paint` method for the `bar` panel.

```
private void quickMenuBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(20, 20), new Point(120, 520), Color.DarkBlue, Color.RoyalBlue);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

        CustomRectangle.FillRoundedRectangle(formGraphics, myBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 500), 25);
        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

But after executing this code, it only prints a rounded rectangle directly onto the form and behind the `bar` panel.

I have other methods that fill a panel with a standard rectangle using  `PaintEventArgs e`:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush , otherBar.ClientRectangle);
```

So obviously I need to use `PaintEventArgs e` in my custom rectangle method, but I do not know how or where to.

If there are better ways than this way of drawing a rounded rectnagles, please share.

Comment: _System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();_ Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Try using Graphics for panel, not for the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally should never be using `CreateGraphics()`. Simply remove this line:

```
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
```

And use `e.Graphics` where you would previously use `formGraphics`. The `Paint` event is basically asking you to "paint something for me, here's the graphics object to paint on".

Since you're already providing a `Graphics` object instance to your rounded rectangle method, no changes are required there.