# C# Rounded Rectangle Corner Inconsistencies

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, rounded-corners

Using C# WinForms, I have a normal label which I fill with rounded corners. The issue I am having is that the resulting corners are not consistently rounded.

For ease of understanding, I have created 4 labels with rounded corners, ranging from a radius of 1 to 5.  I have added a single outline border to the label for ease of visibility, but even without the single outline the results are the same.  I have also zoomed the label images so we can see the corners more clearly.

Using a radius of 1, you can clearly see that the top corners are rounded accordingly, but the bottom borders remain square.

[image: Radius 1]

Using a radius of 2 and 3 respectively, produces the same output at the bottom.

[image: Radius 2 and 3 respectively]

Using a radius of 4 and also 5 respectively, you can clearly see the inconsistencies on all the corners.

[image: Radius 4]

[image: Radius 5]

Generally it wouldn't be too much of a problem if I had a label of a small size, but the user needs to be able to zoom, and then it just looks plain ugly as the radius increases, as the inconsistencies are clearly visible.

The code I am using to create the filled rectangle is supposedly very basic as per example, taken from [How To Draw a Rounded Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853434/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-in-c-sharp)

```
public static GraphicsPath draw_rectangle(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Size size = new Size(diameter, diameter);
        Rectangle arc = new Rectangle(bounds.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        if (radius == 0)
        {
            path.AddRectangle(bounds);
            return path;
        }

        // top left arc  
        path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);

        // top right arc  
        arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);

        // bottom right arc  
        arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);

        // bottom left arc 
        arc.X = bounds.Left;
        path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);

        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;            
    }
```

I have studied and understand what the code does and how it works, I get the angles and the sweep, but I am by no means a seasoned graphics manipulator so I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if there is a way to better the code for all corner consistency.

Your help and\or explanations are appreciated.

Comment: How is the user 'zooming' ?

Comment: @Neil I think he is talking about resizing. So the user will enlarge the form

Comment: It's a simple zoom with a button click; it's just an enlargement of the label and the font, nothing special. On zoom the label background is repainted and obviously the radius increased, and that is where it becomes ugly.

Comment: There is a difference between just enlarging an existing bitmap, and drawing something bigger at a higher resolution.   If you are doing the former, then there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: See the notes and code sample here: [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103) and here: [How can I draw a rounded rectangle as the border for a rounded Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533229/7444103)

Comment: @Neil yes I agree. I am simply changing the label size (height, width) properties, as well as the font size.  For instance, and leaving the font out of this, the label default size is 50,30; so I fill the rounded rectangle with a radius of 10. On "zoom" I set the label size to 100,60; so I fill the rounded rectangle with radius 20. Resizing triggers the paint event where the fill happens, I am not messing with any resolutions.

Comment: @Jimi thanks a million. I had a quick look at the examples. They seem to have a few more lines of code than I do, and the samples look good, I will have a look see.

Comment: The poster of the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853557/5114784) here. I've just found your question. You didn't mention how you do the zooming (`Graphics.ScaleTransform`?), what `SmoothingMode` and `PixelOffsetMode` you use and what the exact coordinates are when you draw/fill things within some specified bounds. These all must be set correctly, especially when you use zooming; otherwise, the result can be misaligned or blurry. If the question is still relevant after a year or so and you provide the missing info I can add an answer.