# How to draw a rounded rectangle with width less than height? C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, discord, rectangles, system.drawing

I have been looking for quite a while for an already pre-made function for creating a rounded rectangle that doesn't cause tearing/glitching like the one below. Credits to [@György Kőszeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853557). This function works fine if the rectangle is big enough. When you start making the rectangle smaller you run into issues like the below image. I am looking for an easy fix for this.

If this issue is on this website and I have missed it, I do apologize for re-asking. (I remember asking this a while back either on here or on another website and receiving an answer that worked amazingly) This issue has been paining me for quite awhile (again).

```
public static GraphicsPath RoundedRect(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Size size = new Size(diameter, diameter);
        Rectangle arc = new Rectangle(bounds.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        if (radius == 0)
        {
            path.AddRectangle(bounds);
            return path;
        }

        // top left arc  
        path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);

        // top right arc  
        arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);

        // bottom right arc  
        arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);

        // bottom left arc 
        arc.X = bounds.Left;
        path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);

        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
```

[image: Error Bar]
[image: Good Bar]

---

**UPDATE:**

In the meantime I have started to use the code below which just overrides the rectangle if the width is less than the height. This creates a perfect circle (the smallest the rounded rectangle can be without the glitching/tearing). A comment was placed on this stating I should not use "tearing" because its simply caused by the math which I understand but I really have no idea what else to call the glitchy rectangle in the image.

Basically I want a oval instead of a circle to correctly reflex the "Exp" value.

```
    public static GraphicsPath RoundedRect(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Size size = new Size(diameter, diameter);
        Rectangle arc = new Rectangle(bounds.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        
        //new code here//
        if(bounds.Height >= bounds.Width)
        {
            bounds.Width = bounds.Height;
        }

        if (radius >= diameter) { 
            path.AddRectangle(bounds); 
            return path; 
        }

        // top left arc   
        path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90); 
        
        // top right arc   
        arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter; 
        path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90); 
        
        // bottom right arc   
        arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter; 
        path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90); 
        
        // bottom left arc  
        arc.X = bounds.Left;
        path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: The image you show doesn't look like tearing at all. It looks like a calculation error.. - Also: What __should__ happen when the width is samller than the diameter??

Comment: @TaW, I didn't say my wording was a hundred percent correct. I see its not "tearing", but its obvious its not rendering the way it should. If the width is smaller than the diameter then it should be showing a little dot in the bar rather than a weird looking "I". I have corrected this in the past but it required alot of shitty calculations that I have not saved. I am looking for a function that basically resolves this on its own. (fixes the "calculation error" in your words.)

Comment: _its not rendering the way it should._ i'd say the path is not set correctly. do not let the rectangle.Width get smaller than diameter.

Comment: Or try this : `if (radius >= diameter)
{
    path.AddRectangle(bounds);
    return path;
}
// top left arc  
arc.X = bounds.Left - diameter;
path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);
// top right arc  
arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter;
path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);
// bottom right arc  
arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter;
path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);
// bottom left arc 
arc.X = bounds.Left - diameter;
path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);`

Comment: That causes the rounded rectangle to be placed offset of where I wanted it. Although I wanted the bar to stay round and shrink farther than the diameter of itself, I will just suffice with the minimum the bar can be is the height. `if(bounds.Height >= bounds.Width){bounds.Width = bounds.Height;}` (just override when width is smaller than height.)

Comment: You can always offset where you draw the path. (`graphics.TranslateTransform(-radius, 0);` )

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work better. Try it with various values for `curveSize`. Note that `curveSize` must be between 1 and the minimum of rect.Width/4 and rect.Height/4:

```
public static GraphicsPath RoundedRect(Rectangle rc, float curveSize)
{
    if (curveSize < 0 || curveSize > rc.Height / 4.0f || curveSize > rc.Width / 4.0f)
        curveSize = 0;

    var result = new GraphicsPath();

    if (curveSize > 0)
    {
        float size4 = curveSize * 4;

        result.AddArc(rc.Right - size4, rc.Top, size4, size4, 270, 90);
        result.AddArc(rc.Right - size4, rc.Bottom - size4, size4, size4, 0, 90);
        result.AddArc(rc.Left, rc.Bottom - size4, size4, size4, 90, 90);
        result.AddArc(rc.Left, rc.Top, size4, size4, 180, 90);

        result.CloseFigure();
    }
    else if (rc.Width > 0 && rc.Height > 0)
    {
        result.AddRectangle(rc);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Although this resolves the tearing issue, I can't seem to make a rounded rectangle like the images. I can only manage to get the rectangle to be curved a certain amount. (More Box Like)

Comment: @ViperzSmurfz Unfortunately I can't see the images because that site is blocked on my work network.