# Hi, I need help for print ticket similar to thermal print

Tags: c#, itext

I have a C# class that has iTextSharp functions embedded, but I can only output PDFs in known formats.

This is the code:

```
public class TicketPDF
{
    public TicketPDF()
    {
        myDocument.AddAuthor("Xauro sistemas");
        myDocument.AddCreator("José Donoso Moscoso");
        myDocument.AddTitle("Venta");
    }

    PdfWriter writer = null;
    PdfContentByte cb = null;
    ArrayList headerLines = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList subHeaderLines = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList totales = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList footerLines = new ArrayList();
    private string headerImage = "";
    bool _DrawItemHeaders = true;
    int count = 0;
    string path = "";
    string file_name = "";
    int maxChar = 40;
    int maxCharDescription = 20;
    int imageHeight = 0;
    float leftMargin = 0;
    float topMargin = 5;
    static int fontSize = 7;

    static BaseFont bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    static Font font = new Font(bfCourier, fontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.LETTER); //Aqui se ponen todos los objetos

    string line = "";

    #region Properties

    public String Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }

    public String FileName
    {
        get { return file_name; }
        set { file_name = value; }
    }

    public String FullFileName
    {
        get { return (String.Format("{0}{1}", path, file_name)); }
    }

    public String HeaderImage
    {
        get { return headerImage; }
        set { if (headerImage != value) headerImage = value; }
    }

    public int MaxChar
    {
        get { return maxChar; }
        set { if (value != maxChar) maxChar = value; }
    }

    public bool DrawItemHeaders
    {
        set { _DrawItemHeaders = value; }
    }

    public int MaxCharDescription
    {
        get { return maxCharDescription; }
        set { if (value != maxCharDescription) maxCharDescription = value; }
    }

    public int FontSize
    {
        get { return fontSize; }
        set { if (value != fontSize) fontSize = value; }
    }

    public Font FontName
    {
        get { return font; }
        set { if (value != font) font = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    public void AddHeaderLine(string line)
    {
        headerLines.Add(line);
    }

    public void AddSubHeaderLine(string line)
    {
        subHeaderLines.Add(line);
    }

    public void AddItem(string cantidad, string item, string price)
    {
        TicketOrderItem newItem = new TicketOrderItem('?');
        items.Add(newItem.GenerateItem(cantidad, item, price));
    }

    public void AddTotal(string name, string price)
    {
        TicketOrderTotal newTotal = new TicketOrderTotal('?');
        totales.Add(newTotal.GenerateTotal(name, price));
    }

    public void AddFooterLine(string line)
    {
        footerLines.Add(line);
    }

    private string AlignRightText(int length)
    {
        string espacios = "";
        int spaces = maxChar - length;

        for (int x = 0; x < spaces; x++)
            espacios += " ";

        return espacios;
    }

    private string DottedLine()
    {
        string dotted = "";

        for (int x = 0; x < maxChar; x++)
            dotted += "=";

        return dotted;
    }

    public bool Print()
    {
        try
        {
            //aqui para generar el PDF
            writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(path + file_name, FileMode.Create));
            myDocument.Open();
            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, fontSize);
            cb.BeginText();
            DrawImage();
            DrawHeader();
            DrawSubHeader();
            DrawItems();
            DrawTotales();
            DrawFooter();
            cb.EndText();
            myDocument.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }

    private float YPosition()
    {
        return (myDocument.PageSize.Height -
            (topMargin + (count * font.CalculatedSize + imageHeight)));
    }

    private void DrawImage()
    {
        try
        {
            if ((headerImage != null) && (headerImage != ""))
            {
                if (File.Exists(headerImage))
                {
                    Image logo = Image.GetInstance(headerImage);
                    double height = ((double)logo.Height / 58) * 15;
                    imageHeight = (int)Math.Round(height) + 3;
                    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(0,
                        myDocument.PageSize.Height - imageHeight);
                    logo.ScaleToFit(logo.Width, imageHeight);
                    myDocument.Add(logo);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
    }

    private void DrawHeader()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string header in headerLines)
            {
                if (header.Length > maxChar)
                {
                    int currentChar = 0;
                    int headerLength = header.Length;

                    while (headerLength > maxChar)
                    {
                        line = header.Substring(currentChar, maxChar);
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line);
                        count++;
                        currentChar += maxChar;
                        headerLength -= maxChar;
                    }

                    line = header;

                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, line.Length - currentChar));
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    line = header;
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            DrawEspacio();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
    }

    private void DrawSubHeader()
    {
        try
        {
            line = DottedLine();
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            DrawEspacio();

            foreach (string subHeader in subHeaderLines)
            {
                if (subHeader.Length > maxChar)
                {
                    int currentChar = 0;
                    int subHeaderLength = subHeader.Length;

                    while (subHeaderLength > maxChar)
                    {
                        line = subHeader;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                        count++;
                        currentChar += maxChar;
                        subHeaderLength -= maxChar;
                    }

                    line = subHeader;

                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, line.Length - currentChar));
                    count++;
                    line = DottedLine();
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line);
                    DrawEspacio();
                }
                else
                {
                    line = subHeader;
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line);
                    count++;
                    line = DottedLine();
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            DrawEspacio();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
    }

    private void DrawItems()
    {
        TicketOrderItem ordIt = new TicketOrderItem('?');

        if (_DrawItemHeaders)
        {
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText("CANT  DESCRIPCION                IMPORTE");
        }

        count++;

        DrawEspacio();

        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            line = ordIt.GetItemCantidad(item);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            line = ordIt.GetItemPrice(item);
            line = AlignRightText(line.Length) + line;
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            string name = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
            leftMargin = 0;

            if (name.Length > maxCharDescription)
            {
                int currentChar = 0;
                int itemLength = name.Length;

                while (itemLength > maxCharDescription)
                {
                    line = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText("      " + line.Substring(currentChar, maxCharDescription));
                    count++;
                    currentChar += maxCharDescription;
                    itemLength -= maxCharDescription;
                }

                line = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText("      " + line.Substring(currentChar,
                    maxCharDescription));
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText("      " + ordIt.GetItemName(item));
                count++;
            }
        }

        leftMargin = 0;
        DrawEspacio();
        line = DottedLine();
        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
        cb.ShowText(line);
        count++;
        DrawEspacio();
    }

    private void DrawTotales()
    {
        TicketOrderTotal ordTot = new TicketOrderTotal('?');

        foreach (string total in totales)
        {
            line = ordTot.GetTotalCantidad(total);
            line = AlignRightText(line.Length) + line;
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            leftMargin = 0;
            line = "" + ordTot.GetTotalName(total);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            count++;
        }

        leftMargin = 0;
        DrawEspacio();
        DrawEspacio();
    }

    private void DrawFooter()
    {
        foreach (string footer in footerLines)
        {
            if (footer.Length > maxChar)
            {
                int currentChar = 0;
                int footerLength = footer.Length;

                while (footerLength > maxChar)
                {
                    line = footer;
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                    count++;
                    currentChar += maxChar;
                    footerLength -= maxChar;
                }

                line = footer;
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                line = footer;
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                count++;
            }
        }
        leftMargin = 0;
        DrawEspacio();
    }

    private void DrawEspacio()
    {
        line = "";
        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
        cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, fontSize);
        cb.ShowText(line);
        count++;
    }
}

public class TicketOrderItem
{
    char[] delimitador = new char[] { '?' };
    public TicketOrderItem(char delimit)
    {
        delimitador = new char[] { delimit };
    }

    public string GetItemCantidad(string TicketOrderItem)
    {
        string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
        return delimitado[0];
    }

    public string GetItemName(string TicketOrderItem)
    {
        string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
        return delimitado[1];
    }

    public string GetItemPrice(string TicketOrderItem)
    {
        string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
        return delimitado[2];
    }

    public string GenerateItem(string cantidad,
        string itemName, string price)
    {
        return cantidad + delimitador[0] +
            itemName + delimitador[0] + price;
    }
}

public class TicketOrderTotal
{
    char[] delimitador = new char[] { '?' };
    public TicketOrderTotal(char delimit)
    {
        delimitador = new char[] { delimit };
    }

    public string GetTotalName(string totalItem)
    {
        string[] delimitado = totalItem.Split(delimitador);
        return delimitado[0];
    }

    public string GetTotalCantidad(string totalItem)
    {
        string[] delimitado = totalItem.Split(delimitador);
        return delimitado[1];
    }

    public string GenerateTotal(string totalName,
        string price)
    {
        return totalName + delimitador[0] + price;
    }
}
```

It is used as follows:

```
public static void CrearBoleta(DTE dte, string pathOut = null)
{
    TicketPDF boleta = new TicketPDF();
    boleta.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathOut)+"\\";
    boleta.FileName =  $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathOut)}.PDF";
    boleta.HeaderImage = null;

    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_01");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_02");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_03");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_04");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_05");

    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 1");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 2");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 3");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 4");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 5");

    int Cantidad = 1;
    string Producto = "Stacarbone 100";
    int Total = 1500;
    // Detalles
    boleta.AddItem( Cantidad.ToString(), Producto.Substring(0, 11), Total.ToString() );

    boleta.Print();

}
```

and generates the following PDF in Letter format:

[image: output PDF letter format]

But I need to generate a PDF similar to this one, which is in 80mm format, does anyone know how to make my class generate in this format?

[image: expected pdf]

i use iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 in my project.

Greetings and thanks

Comment: It's **length** (-t-h at the end) - not "lenght" ...

Comment: If you'd like to consider a different approach, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557129/how-to-create-and-print-a-table-using-drawing-vb-net/71562125#71562125) may be helpful (it's in VB.NET though).

Comment: You in your code use `new Document(PageSize.LETTER)` to generate a PDF in Letter format. Now guess where you have to change something to get a PDF in a different format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a document constructor that takes a rectangle as argument

```
public Document(Rectangle pageSize)
```

Presumably you can pass in  any size you like

Rectangle is here https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Rectangle.cs