# In C# Windows app how to print multiple cards on a single page

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing

I am building a app that needs to print some "cards" for inventory counting similar to below.
[sample print job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfPwO.png)

Some of the data will come from the database like Item & Location.  Based on the parameters defined on the app, that will drive how many cards per page will be needed.  For example if the location (i.e. row / shelf) you could have 95 items and that would be broken into x number of pages.  If I can have 10 cards per page that would be 10 pages, but the past page would only have 5 cards.

I have been working with the .NET printing class, but can't figure out how to get more than 1 card to print on a page.  I also checked on the learn.microsoft.com and wasn't able to get the answer.  I am assuming I would have to handle this in the PrintPageEventHandler event, but just not sure how to.

I tried setting the rows & columns but that didn't see to work.  My testing has been with the PrintPreviewControl for not waste paper.

If there is any sample code or document that you could point me to I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to provide at least some kind of example that we can work on, framework you are working on etc.

Comment: This is complicated.  I would start by reading following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/

Comment: It's not clear wihether or not these _cards_ already exist (on sheets of paper or card stock) or whether you're printing the entire _card_ as well as, the information that populates the fields. If you're using card stock (or paper), the following may be of interest: [Use mail merge for bulk email, letters, labels, and envelopes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705)

Comment: Is this a desktop app? WinForms? WPF? MAUI? [`PrintPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage) sounds like a good place to start; what have you done, and why do you think that “didn't see to work”?

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear on this.  Let me try to be a bit more clear.  First off this is not developed yet.  This is the first time I have printed in C#, I have done it many times in other languages.  This will be a .NET Windows Form desktop app.  I am using v7.0 framework currently.  The output will be to a standard blank letter sized paper on a laser printer.  I am just trying to get a good source that can explain the class so I can get the layout as it is needed.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562125/10024425

Comment: @user246821 Thanks for the link, this looks like it will be helpful!